# Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, yarnpkg, corepack

I'm trying to enable 'corepack' by running

```
corepack enable
```

according to the directions here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

but getting this error

> Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason the downloaded `node` gave me all sorts of permission issues. What *does* work is using `nvm` to install `node`.

First install `nvm` using these directions https://tecadmin.net/install-nvm-macos-with-homebrew/

Then follow these next steps:

> nvm install --lts

> corepack enable

> yarn

Answer (score 12):

I experienced it today. Adding sudo worked fine for me.

```
sudo corepack enable
```

Answer (score 8):

Encountered this myself and it seems like the issue was that the circleci environment doesn't allow access to the default location corepack adds it's binary symlinks (`/usr/local/bin/...`). For me it was fixed by instead using `~/bin` for the corepack install directory:

```
corepack enable --install-directory ~/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command it will run

```
sudo corepack enable
```